# How to limit my row or column that don't have a value in Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel

I want to limit my row or column. See the picture, the highlighted part is the range.

[image]

below is my code.

```
Excel.Range range = _currentSheet.UsedRange;
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl /*Limit Column Count*/; cCnt++)
    {
        //str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value2;
        str = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value2);
        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the picture

Comment: its OK :D hope you can help me

Comment: Please pick a language. Not both vb and C#

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the number of rows with data
rw = _currentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
//get the number of columns with data
cl = _currentSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
```

I used this code then it work!